# Multiple Permission at once not working in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get 2 permissions at once but Iam unable to do so.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, Array<String>(2) { 
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS; 
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
        1);
    }
}
```

It only asks for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and not `READ_CONTACTS`. Actually, If I write `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` one first and `READ_CONTACTS` after that then it will only ask for contact and not `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array(size: Int, init: (Int) -> T)
```

is the [constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/-init-.html) for the `Array` class which takes the number of elements it should contain, and an `init` function which maps the index to an actual array element.

Here is what your code does, written in a more verbose way

```
val a = Array<String>(size = 2, init = { index: Int ->
    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS; // nothing
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE // returned by the lambda for each index
})
```

Result:

> [Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
>   Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]

So, you would be better of using the `arrayOf` function in this case, since you don't want to genereate your array elements but rather specify them explicitely.

Comment: I have used arrayof still it is asking for only last permission, can you tell me why

Answer (score 2):

Use this code for multiple permission in kotlin

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context as Activity,
                                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                                PERMISSION_CAMER)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Array<String>(2) { 
    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS ; 
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
}
```

This initializer always returns `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, the first line does not do anything. You should probably be using the `arrayOf` function to construct the array instead.